# QObject deleteLater() and nested objects deletion

Tags: c++11, qt5

Does calling `deleteLater()` on a Qt object also deletes nested objects or not? For instance, I have a layout in which I add several widgets and layouts. Sometimes, I need to redraw or delete some layouts and/or widgets:

```
QWidget* blankWidget = new QWidget(this);
grid = new QGridLayout();
blankWidget->setLayout(grid);
setWidget(blankWidget);

QVBoxLayout* vBox = new QVBoxLayout();
realTimeCheckBox = new QCheckBox("Real Time Rendering", this);
vBox->addWidget(realTimeCheckBox);

grid->addLayout(vBox, 1, 0);
```

Is it safe to call in another method something like this?

```
grid->deleteLater();
```

Does it delete each nested layouts and widgets of the grid?

### Update

Tested with the `destroyed(QObject*)` signal. As underlined in the comments, it works.

Comment: Yes, it does. Calling `deleteLater` is practically equivalent to `delete` on a `QObject`, except that the destruction does not take place immediately. Since `QObject`'s destructor also destructs all children, all your layouts and/or widgets owned by the parent layout will also be destructed.

Comment: I'd formulate that as an answer :)